# Data binding in Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have a collection of data:

```
$scope.myThings = [
  {
    name: "Andrew"
  }
];
```

And I create an `ng-repeat`:

```
<my-thing ng-repeat="thing in myThings" thing-data="thing" />
```

MyThing directive:

```
angular.module('myMod').directive('myThing', [function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    scope: {
      'thingData': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
}]);
```

Everything works without an issue. However, say I got new data and wanted to iterate through `$scope.myThings`:

```
someMethod.getNewData().then(function(newData) {
    _.each(newData, function(d) {
      var existingThing = _.find($scope.myThings, function(t) {
        return t.ID == d.ID;
      });

      existingThing.name = d.name;
    });
  });
```

Everything seems to work, but the data in the directive doesn't reflect the new value.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you in the digest cycle when updating it (ie where is new data coming from)? otherwise you have to call `$scope.$digest()`?

Comment: The new data comes from an AJAX call that runs periodically.

Comment: show that code. if you aren't using `$http` you have to use `$scope.$digest()`.

Comment: Calling $scope.$digest() doesn't seem to work. I tried calling it after `existingThing.name = d.name` and outside of the loop entirely.

Comment: can you create a MCRE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think its not updating as you are using other libraries. Can you create jsfiddle.

Comment: It depends on how you use `scope.thingData` in directive. The code you posted is fine and will work if you use directive bound data properly.